# Transform 3D data into 2D color map like Matlab's surf/imagesc

Tags: graphics, data

I have a bunch of 3D data (x, y coordinates and values) which is generated in Matlab and I need to render them in a 2D color map with certain axis ranges. Here are the Matlab code and the generated figure.

```
rho = linspace(0, 80, 100);
phi = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
[PHI,RHO] = meshgrid(phi, rho);
dat = rand(size(PHI)); % data was generated in cylindrical coordinate
[x, y] = pol2cart(PHI, RHO);
surf(x, y, data,'edgecolor','none'); shading interp;
view(0, 90);
axis equal; axis off;
xlim([-50, 50]); ylim([-50, 50])
save('data.mat', 'x', 'y', 'dat')
```

[image: render 3d data into a 2d colormap]

In ***Mathematica***, I imported these data by evaluating

```
{x, y, dat} = Import["data.mat", "MAT"]
```

but I have no idea how to render them as shown above. I tried

```
ListPlot3D[{x, y, dat}]
```

It gave a 3D pattern but was extremely slow because I have a lot of data. Could anyone give me a hint to tackle this problem?

Comment: Could you please post the data for those of us who don't have matlab?

Comment: I guess the sample code could be: data = Flatten[
   Table[{r Cos[i], r Sin[i], RandomReal[{0, Pi}]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 
     2 Pi/100.}, {r, 0, 80, 80/100.}], 1];ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue]

Answer (score 6):

MATLAB's `surf` plots a parametric surface with the point $(x_i,y_j)$ colored according to the value in $\mathrm{dat}_{i,j}$. This is easily achieved with `ListDensityPlot` as follows:

```
ListDensityPlot[Thread[Flatten /@ {x, y, dat}], PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks rm -rf, it works but take a lot of time if we upsample the data as commented by @halmir, say, from 100 to 500. Any idea to accelerate it?

Comment: It's probably because `ListDensityPlot` interpolates and tries to resample/refine it to a regular grid behind the scenes. I can't test this right now, but I'll take a look later in the day.